# Spring Boot Application won't start (IllegalStateException could not evaluate condition on DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I've tried to start my Spring Boot Application using IntelliJ. However, I cannot seem to make it work no matter whatever solutions I tried to implement to fix it. I believe it has something to do with `spring.autoconfigure` package, yet the root problem remains a mystery to me.

I am trying to take advantage of both `Maven Multi Module System` as well as `Java Platform Module System`. Below is my `pom.xml`, `module-info.java` files and project structure.

**Project Structure**

[image: Simplified Project Structure]

Note that there is a parent `pom.xml` file and each sub-module has its own `pom.xml` file. Each sub-module has its own `module-info.java` file as well.

**Parent pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>Demo Project</name>
    <description>Demo Project Description</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <!--Add each module here -->
    <modules>
        <module>webapp</module>
        <module>persistence</module>
        <module>facade</module>
        <module>service</module>
        <module>security</module>
        <module>domain</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.example.MainApplication</mainClass>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>
                                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            </exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <!-- For testing -->
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

**webapp pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <!--    <version>0.0.1</version>-->

    <artifactId>webapp</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Add dependencies for `webapp` module here -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>facade</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**webapp module-info.java**

```
module webapp {
    requires domain;
    requires facade;

    requires spring.web;
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires spring.context;
}
```

**Below is what I tried:**
So when I run the application as it is I get the following exception

```
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher (in module spring.boot.devtools) cannot access class com.example.MainApplication (in module webapp) because module webapp does not export com.example to module spring.boot.devtools
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:361)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:558)
    at spring.boot.devtools@2.5.1/org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
```

What I did to tackle this problem was changing webapp/module-info.java from

```
module webapp {
}
```

to

```
open module webapp {
}
```

Aftwerwards, though, I got the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration due to javax/sql/DataSource not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
    at spring.boot.autoconfigure@2.5.1/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:54) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.3.8/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.3.8/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:489) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.3.8/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:140) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.3.8/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.3.8/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.3.8/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.3.8/org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.3.8/org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.3.8/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:na]
    at spring.context@5.3.8/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@2.5.1/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@2.5.1/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@2.5.1/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@2.5.1/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at spring.boot@2.5.1/org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at webapp/com.example.MainApplication.main(MainApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at spring.boot.devtools@2.5.1/org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.1.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/sql/DataSource
    at spring.boot.devtools@2.5.1/org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration$DevToolsDataSourceCondition.getMatchOutcome(DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:183) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at spring.boot.autoconfigure@2.5.1/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.1.jar:na]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.sql.DataSource
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

- I tried setting `spring.devtools.restart.enabled=false`. Same error followed.
- I tried removing `spring-boot-devtools` from the list of dependencies. No error log yet start process exits with error code 0
- I tried adding `h2` database dependency just to see what happens. No good.
- I tried changing `spring-boot-devtools` `<scope>` value and even commenting it out. No good.
- I tried excluding `DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class` from AutoConfiguration. No good.
- I tried adding `exports com.example;` to module-info.java. No good.
- If I run `mvn test`, `mvn clean install`, `mvn spring-boot:run`, I don't get a single error and server is running just fine.
- `MainApplication.java` resides at `webapp/src/main/java/com/example/MainApplication.java`.

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Why is `spring.autoconfigure` trying to find a `DataSource`? Is `IntelliJ`'s classpath messed up, and I need to update its dependencies manually? If I configure a proper database (such as `mssql`), would I still be facing this issue going forward?

What confuses me the most is that I get no error triggering the server to run by typing `mvn spring-boot:run` command. To be honest, this is what makes me think the problem has to do with `IntelliJ's` classpath settings rather than project structure and configuration.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your persistence module should add a requires for the SQL stuff. Else that class isn't available. imho the issue is the other way around, Intellij uses proper modules whereas your command line doesn't (which is why it works).

Comment: Hey. @M.Deinum thanks for the reply. For those who may come across the same problem trying to build a project using JPMS, my solution to this problem was adding ```requires org.apache.tomcat.embed.core;``` to my module-info.java file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing `module-info.java` as the following resolved the problem for me

```
open module webapp {
    requires spring.web;
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires spring.context;
    
    requires org.apache.tomcat.embed.core;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Java 17 and solved it by adding to my open module in modules-info.java, the following:

```java
requires java.sql;
```

Using Spring Framework 6, Spring Boot 3.